# How to set a component's param dynamically?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component-params

To retreive a param I use:

```
$myparam = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_mycomponent')->get('myparam');
```

But what is the right method to store a component's param?

Comment: I mean apart from using the Options button

Comment: If you aren't using the options button, how are you getting the value that you want to store?

Comment: Don't really understand your question. From any location, in another components controller for example, I would like to set a new value to some other components param.

Comment: You could try to build a component using http://www.component-creator.com and view the code it generates when adding parameters to your component.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Many of our component's parameters depend on external conditions, so we need to periodically change them with some overnight processing.  Here's the code we use (adapted for use with com_content).

```
// Load the current component params.
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');
// Set new value of param(s)
$params->set('show_title', 1);

// Save the parameters
$componentid = JComponentHelper::getComponent('com_content')->id;
$table = JTable::getInstance('extension');
$table->load($componentid);
$table->bind(array('params' => $params->toString()));

// check for error
if (!$table->check()) {
    echo $table->getError();
    return false;
}
// Save to database
if (!$table->store()) {
    echo $table->getError();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks very great! So I was not overlooking an existing method, it really needs some extra code indeed. I'll markt your answer GOOD  asap, when I have tested it. (But since you're already using this, It probably is the right answer anyway)

Comment: Happy to help...can't keep up with the Joomla versions as well as I'd like, so there may well be a method, but this one has been working for us for awhile now...cheers